# I want to change css style using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to append font style and type in textarea as per user requirement. I tried but my script is not working...

```
function run() {
var fontType = document.getElementById("font_type").value;
var fontSize = document.getElementById("font_size").value;

var textArea = document.getElementById("msg");
//alert(fontType+fontSize);

textArea.style.font-size = fontSize ;
textArea.style.font-family = fontType;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
textArea.style.fontSize = fontSize ;
textArea.style.fontFamily = fontType;
```

Otherwise your JavaScript is evaluated as:

```
textArea.style.font - size = fontSize;
textArea.style.font - family = fontType;
```

... which doesn't make *any* sense (and so throws a `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`).

This conversion (`something-something` to `somethingSomething`) is consistent when changing all style properties in JavaScript (`border-radius` -> `borderRadius` etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
textArea.style.fontSize = fontSize ;
textArea.style.fontFamily = fontType;
```