# What's the proper syntax, in JavaScript, for changing css via conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

here is what I've got and I know it isn't right. Basically, I'm trying to say, "If the height of the div called three is 445, change the background image to this jpg."

```
if ( ".three" == height:"445" ) {".three.style.background-image"= 'url(images/2.jpg)'};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, that's a mess... You should start from the very basics.

Comment: How many elements are there with that class? If it's just one, why not give it an ID? Then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10978557/218196.

Comment: Is that `<div id="three">` or `<div class="three">`?

Comment: . is always a class, right? # refers to id

Comment: In CSS, yes. What's your (representative) HTML that you're trying to style with this conditional?

Comment: If this is the only div called three, you should make it an ID. It's a lot easier to look up elements by ID than by class in JavaScript.

Comment: Felix, that example isn't a conditional statement.

Comment: I am just asking for the proper syntax because I can't find it anywhere. Is it even possible to change CSS with a conditional statement?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your HTML is along the lines of:

```
<div class="three" style="height: 445px;">
    <p>Some arbitrary content.</p>
</div>
```

Then the following will work:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('three');
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
    if (parseInt(elems[i].style.height, 10) == 445) {
        elems[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/2.png)';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MDa3d/), using `background-color` instead of `background-image` for simplicity).

If, however, you're using CSS to style the elements:

```
.three {
    height: 445px;
}
```

Then you'd need to use `window.getComputedStyle()`:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('three');
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
    console.log(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null).height, 10));
    if (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null).height, 10) == 445) {
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MDa3d/2/), (using, as above, `background-color` instead of `background=image`).

If you were to use a JavaScript library, then this could be simplified somewhat; with jQuery (for example, though I'm not especially advocating jQuery, it's just the library with which I'm most familiar), the above could be rewritten as:

```
$('.three').css('background-image', function(){
    return $(this).height() == 445 ? 'images/2.png' : '';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MDa3d/3/), (again using `background-color` instead of `background=image`).

Note that Internet Explorer works differently to most browsers, in that `window.getComputedStyle()` isn't available, there is `currentStyle()`, however (but without Windows I can't offer advice on how to use it).

For guidance, and reference, on JavaScript I'd recommend (above almost all else) reading through the Mozilla Developer Network's [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript).

References:

- [`currentStyle` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style).
- [`for () {/*...*/}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [jQuery library](http://www.jquery.com/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Wow, that looks much more complicated.

Comment: Much more complicated? Maybe, but it works; which I assumed was the important thing.